# sshfs: cannot set file timestamp

Tags: linux, networking, unix, sshfs, fuse

Using sshfs with autofs on Ubuntu, I cannot set timestamps on remote files:

```
$ touch /sshfs/server/some/file
touch: setting times of `/sshfs/sshfs/server/some/file': Permission denied
```

I do have write access to the file. The problem surfaced because files copied to the remote don't get the original's timestamp, but the time of when the copy was done.

If I ssh to the server, I can also change the timestamp without trouble. It only fails through sshfs.

```
$ cat /etc/auto.sshfs 

afserver -fstype=fuse,sshfs_debug,rw,nodev,nonempty,noatime,allow_other,max_read=65536   :sshfs\#my_username@server.domain.lan:/

$ stat  /sshfs/server/some/file
...
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1003/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (  100/   users)
```

Comment: In case the problem persists, can you log into the **server** with  account 'my_username' (the one you use for sshfs), execute `ls -l /some/file`, then execute `id` and post it? Can you run `id` logged in on your Ubuntu computer and post it too?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=26780130 (FUSE mailing list - basically, what SSHFS implements), you are experiencing this problem, because filesystem used in /sshfs/server/some/ does not handle the attributes handler used. There is no solution whatsoever for SSHFS implementation that you are using.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't see that you have "noatime" option set. Why? Remove it. That should solve the issue here.

Comment: You obviously don't understand what `noatime` means/does. When you `touch` a file, the point is to set the `mtime`, not the `atime`.

Comment: Daniel, not exactly true. `touch`ing a file, gets you both, not just setting `mtime`.